# MediaTek 8516 SoM support for "OK Google" Wake Word

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

Is anyone aware whether MediaTek 8516 SoM supports wake-word out-of-the-box for Actions on Device or does the developer have to rely on custom wake-word engines and integrate custom wake-word with Assistant SDK using gRPC.

Wake word with Android Things on RPi is still not supported, but for commercial speakers it seems like one has to stick with google certified SoM.

(NOTE: MediaTek 8516 SoM is a certified Google Assistant system on module with Android Things for commercial speaker development)

Comment: I'm not sure if you can get a MediaTek SOM with Android Things.

Comment: @NickFelker Here's a link from MediaTek that claims it is certified SoM to support Assistant [link] https://www.mediatek.com/blog/mt8516-som-create-your-own-android-things. Given the form link for "Building Commercial Product" is no longer working, we are wondering who can confirm whether wake word support will be provided by Google or do we have to build our own using external wake-word engine? If external, then are we allowed to use any custom wake-word or is it limited to "Ok Google" & "Hey Google". Appreciate your help & prompt response Nick.

Comment: @NickFelker after reading [link] (https://venturebeat.com/2019/02/12/google-refocuses-android-thing-as-a-platform-for-oem-partners/) now I understand your insight. Is there any way we can get any information about Commercial product certification with embedded Google Assistant, so we can plan our development strategy.

Comment: If you are in contact with Google's business development team, they can provide you with more resources and answers. If you are not, you will not get the sufficient resources you'd want to create a commercial product.